# Problems changing port and IP address of my mongo service from mongod.conf file for remote access

Tags: mongodb

Thank you very much for admitting me in the group, I have been working with the mongo Db manager in its version 4.0 for a few days and for work reasons I saw the need to create a service that would have remote access to a server that has a Windows server as its operating system 2012, I have tried to modify my mongod.conf file, in order to add the server ip in the bindIp attribute and I have enabled the security: authorization attribute, I save the changes as administrator, I restart the service and still the changes are not reflected when I try to create a connection with the added Ip address, I also try to create a new configuration rule to change the boot port and the same thing happens to me, I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with the solution to this problem that has me in the search for its possible solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arzpH.jpg)

Comment: The IP address **127.0.0.1** means that the MongoDB server will only accept connections from the local system. You should change the value to be **0.0.0.0** if you want other computers to be able to connect to the MongoDB server.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried to make the change and it seems that the service does not take the modifications that I make in my mongo.conf file, I tried to test with a telnet and the default localhost is still enabled